# Rails test spec will not build my user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

There are so many moving parts to Rails testing that it's difficult to debug a failing test sometimes.

As a case in point, I am attempting to use zeus, guard, rspec, capybara, Poltergeist, PhantomJS, and FactoryGirl to simply build a User factory.

I am met with the following error message:

`spec/models/user.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  describe 'Factories' do
    it { expect(build :user).to be_valid }
  end
end
```

`spec/factories/users.rb`

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    sequence(:email)      { |n| Forgery(:internet).email_address }
    sequence(:company)    { |n| Forgery(:name).company_name }
    password              "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
  end
end
```

Now I have a request spec that fails on the following line, which is the setup at the beginning:

```
let!(:user) { login_user }
```

The failure is this:

```
 Failure/Error: let!(:user) { login_user }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `last_logged_in_at=' for #<User:0x007fe60aca95e8>
 # ./app/models/user.rb:136:in `set_login_time'
 # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:24:in `create'
 # ./spec/support/login_macros.rb:7:in `login_user'
 # ./spec/requests/app_integration_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./custom_plan.rb:12:in `spec'
 # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

So the problem appears to be that since User is not a real object, there is no such attribute as `last_logged_in_at`. So I should have to mock that somewhere. I tried putting this inside the factory code:

```
before(:build) do |u|
  u.stub!(:read_attribute).with(:last_logged_in_at).and_return(Time.now)
end
```

The error remains the same. The test simply can not find this attribute. Keep in mind this code works perfectly in the browser. I am out of my league. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please learn raw testing before adding the hard stuff. Then run your tests as frequently as possible, preferably out of a keystroke in your IDE. Then test failures are easy to diagnose when they most likely refer to the most recently edited code.

Comment: Does { expect(build :user).to be_valid } pass? Also please post the definition of login_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your test db schema up-to-date?

```
rake db:test:prepare
```